# Reordering items in a ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I compute two series and store them in a dataframe which I then melt and plot. One of the variables (SD(Sharpe Ratio)) is much smaller than the other (T). I would like T to be the first item in the legend and SD(Sharpe Ratio) to be the second. I have struggled a bit with fct_relevel, but without success. Can I do this in Base R (4.2.2)?

Minimal example:

```
alpha  <- 0.25
df     <- data. Frame(SR = seq(0.25, 2, 0.25))
df[["SD(Sharpe Ratio)"]] <- sqrt(1 + df[["SR"]]^2/2)
df[["T"]]  <- (1 + df[["SR"]]^2)/(alpha^2 * df[["SR"]]^2)
df_melt <- df |> 
            melt(id.vars = "SR", variable.name = "Item")
```

I now plot the melted dataframe:

```
  df_melt |>
    ggplot(aes(x = SR, y = value)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Item), linewidth = 0.75)
```

How can I reorder the items in the legend so that T is the first item?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `relevel`.

```r
df_melt$Item <- relevel(df_melt$Item, "T")
df_melt |>
    ggplot(aes(x = SR, y = value)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Item), linewidth = 0.75)
```

[image: ggplot with "T" first in legend]